# How to interact with Google Play Services to query for images?

Tags: android, search, google-play-services, google-image-search

### Background

I'm trying to figure out how to find images from the Internet, and show them on Android (as thumbnails and full screen).

### The problem

Not only Google has deprecated the previous way to do it, but now they have documentation for a new kind called "custom search":

- https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/customsearch/v1
- https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/DeveloperGuide
- https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/java/latest/

Later, Google has chosen that developers should use "Google Play Services", but again, I can't find the correct commands for this specific task. 
This is what I've found:
https://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html

I've found a lot of links, but don't know which of them are the best that Google suggests, and I also don't know how come there are barely any samples (let alone in Java and search feature) ...

### The question

Since everything got merged, and since there is few documentation (and examples), I wish to ask if there is an example of how to achieve searching of images using this new SDK, and maybe if there is a library that makes it easier.

I also wish to ask what will happen for devices that don't have the Google Play services - will it still work?

Comment: We need a little more information on what your searching for if your not looking for images from picasa then your looking for images from some other web site.  What site are looking for images from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Only [some of the Google APIs are available via Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html) library (eg: maps, drive, ads etc). Using Play services library gives you some advantages like [easy to use client libraries, common authorization, automatic updates](https://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html) on devices etc.
- `Custom Search API` currently is not one of them. So we need to use the other option - [Google APIs Client Library for Android](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android). Using this, you can [access most of Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/). Additionally, this does not require client devices having play services.
- For a sample test, use [`android-async-http`](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) and do a below GET request (you will need to get [API Key](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and [CX key](https://www.google.com/cse/)). eg: Image search for unicorn:

  ```
  GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=unicorn&cx={CX}&searchType=image&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
  ```

  - you can [generate other queries and check out the JSON you get here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list)

    .
- Sample JSON output for image search looks like :

  ```
  "items": [
      {
      "kind": "customsearch#result",
      "title": "Unicorn - Monster Wiki - a reason to leave the closet closed and ...",
      "htmlTitle": "<b>Unicorn</b> - Monster Wiki - a reason to leave the closet closed and <b>...</b>",
      "link": "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090425203919/monster/images/c/c4/Unicorn.jpg",
      "displayLink": "monster.wikia.com",
      "snippet": "Unicorn",
      "htmlSnippet": "<b>Unicorn</b>",
      "mime": "image/jpeg",
          "image": {
          "contextLink": "http://monster.wikia.com/wiki/Unicorn",
          "height": 375,
          "width": 500,
          "byteSize": 235870,
          "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRcX2jgPxf-0yzrfV5piHuiKpDzSCGpJNbB0vywH-nqvmeL1-gL22uaZjb5",
          "thumbnailHeight": 98,
          "thumbnailWidth": 130
          }
      },
      ...
      ...
   ]
  ```
- Pull out image urls, and use a image loader [`android library like Picasso`](http://square.github.io/picasso/) - (not related to [`google picasa`](http://picasa.google.com/)) to download the thumbnails and full images, for use in your app

**Sample code**:

- create a hello world app in android studio with blank activity. Add below 2 lines of dependencies to build.gradle for "app" module

  ```
      compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
      compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
  ```
- add an `ImageView` in activity_main.xml for showing result from custom google image search

  ```
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
  ```
- in `onCreate`, do a HTTPS `GET` [Custom Google Search Image Query](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) using AsyncHttpClient and use `Picasso` library to show the first image result in your `imageView`

  ```
  String imgQuery = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=unicorn&cx={CX_KEY}&searchType=image&key={API_KEY}";
  new AsyncHttpClient().get(imgQuery, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
      public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
          String imgJson = new String(response);
          String firstImage = imgJson.split("link\": \"")[1].split("\"")[0];
          Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(firstImage).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView));
      }
      public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {}
  });
  ```

  - And the result :

[image: image search]

Comment: 1. So "Google Play Services" can't handle searches? 2. What is the "CX" key, and how come the generator doesn't have it? 3. Why do yo need any key, let alone 2 keys? 4. About the API key link, do I need to choose "enable API" and then choose "custom search" ? 5. They say its max usage is 1000 requests a day (yet when you enter inside they say it's 100 for some reason). Does it mean 1000 requests per user, or per app? 6. Can you please provide a sample code for the above query?

Comment: This is not an example it just shows json.

Comment: @danny117 I know. that's one of the questions I asked in the comment.

Comment: @androiddeveloper added example code. The keys are needed by anyone using Google APIs not just for android, or image search. API limits are part of custom search apis, not specific to android, [basic is free but you can get more with pay](https://www.google.com/cse/)

Comment: @ashoke Thank you for the sample code. So there isn't any cap for the number of queries? Why does it need 2 keys?

Comment: @ashoke I meant: does Google caps the number of queries? If so, how much and in which way? does it cap it per IP? per app?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I believe they do in general (nothing special android). It could vary depending on several factors..Please [see here for full details](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#monitoringandfiltering) it lets you manage your caps.

Comment: @ashoke Ok then, but I would really like to know this too. I can upvote your comments if you answer about it too.